# Jqgrid add and edit dialog width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I created a jqgrid with some functionality. It working very well. I have a big form to add and edit box. So i would like to set the width of the form, so i search and get the code from google and place it in my code. This also working.But the success and error message not shown in my grid. If i remove these two line means working well but the width not set.

```
{closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:800},   // Edit options
{closeOnEscape:true, recreateForm: true, width:800},   // Add options
```

Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Try my answer, if u didn't get the output correct, then post some more of your code. We will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works fine for me,

```
$("#ButtonId").click(function () {
            jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new", { height: 330, width: 350, addCaption: "Add form", recreateForm: true, closeAfterAdd: true });
});
```

In the above, you can give the **height** & **width** as you need. The same thing for *edit form* too.

Comment: It's working. But the form closed suddenly.I can't get the success or error message my main thing is to get the  success and error message while add or edit form,

Comment: @user3085540:  you can use **success function** in ajax to show success alerts, probably the form will close after add.

Comment: @user3085540:  This option will helpful for u. **afterSubmit** fires after the data is posted to the server. Typical this
event is used to recieve status form server if the data is posted with success. Parameters to this event are the returned data from the request and array of the posted values of type name:value. **For ex:** have a look here http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/handling-response-from-aftersubmit-method/

Comment: @user3085540:  Have one more look here(Tony's answer): http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/aftersubmit-event/